# Does an $X$ exist so $X \simeq \Omega^n Y$ for all $n$, and X is not an infinite loop space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

Are there examples of spaces $X$ that have the property $X \simeq \Omega ^n Y$ with $Y$ depending on $n$, for all natural $n$, with $X$ not an infinite loop space?

I have a feeling these things should exist, and I imagine they have been studied.

Comment: You perhaps have to add a definition of "infinite loop space", as some authors seem to define "infinite loop space" as "is an $n$-fold loop space for all $n$".

Comment: @max What I thought the standard definition of infinite loop space typically was is “$X_0$ is an infinite loop space if $X_0$ is homotopy equivalent to the loop space of $X_1$; $X_1$ is homotopy equivalent to the loop space of $X_2$; ...”

Comment: I thought so too, but checked and saw at least one document with the definition I mentioned. Now with the comments your question is entirely clear however, so it's fine